# Read header of hive file in python

Tags: python, hive

I want to read a hive table in python to create a user-defined function. But I do not know how to find the schema of the hive table that carries the variable name and data type. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the file format of your hive file? They can be in different formats. Look at section 2 here: https://www.mapr.com/blog/what-kind-hive-table-best-your-data#.VfyMzRFVhBc

Comment: Type `hive` at the command line.  Then type `use <name of database>;` in the hive shell.  Then type `describe extended <name of table>;`

Comment: Thanks Chad & GoBrewers14- I am looking at text files which have been converted to hive tables. Actually i want to create a UDF in python that would pick all numeric variables from hive table in question. Is there a way i could call "describe extended" function from python?